# Private S3 object accessible when trying to open from link first time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my S3 I have all of my items set to private, but added a bucket policy to allow my site to read files. This works fine.

The thing I don't understand, is that when I copy the link and open it in the browser, it will actually open the file the first time I try, which shouldn't be happening, but then it works from there on, not allowing the user access.

**Why does it allow the user to get through the first time they try?**

Also they can access the file 1 time again after clearing their cache. I tried playing around with the cache metadata of the objects and that didn't seem to make a difference. However when I click the link in my s3 console it is never accessible. Does anyone have an explanation for this and how do I solve this?

EDIT:

```
       {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "http referer policy example",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Allow get requests originated from www.example.com and example.com",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "http://www.dev.example.co/*",
                    "http://dev.example.co/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Thats my bucket policy. All objects have the canned ACL set to private.

I also noticed that it seems the bucket policy is being ignored totally. I made a new bucket and set the policy to deny any access, as well having the objects set to private, yet my site is still able to load those objects? Any idea?

EDIT 2 SOLUTION:

For anyone else struggling with something like this, it turns the issue was related to browser cache. What was happening was that when someone viewed the file on my site, the file would be stored in cache, which would allow at user to open the link in a new window from cache, thus not being blocked the s3 bucket policy since the file was just opened from cache and no request was actually sent to amazon (as far as I know). When I changed the Cache-Control parameter of my object to 'no-cache', I no longer had this issue since the files could not be called from cache and my bucket policy prevented them from being accessed. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing the ACLs you've set for it

Comment: When you access the object from the Amazon S3 console, are you using the "Actions/Open" command, or are you retrieving the URL from the **Properties** section on the right? The reason I ask is that the **Open** command creates a Pre-signed URL to grant access while the link in **Properties** is anonymous.